# Element becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I created a simple library, and I'm trying to change the style of an element in the library. Very simple thing.

```
content[0].removeChild(content[0].firstElementChild);
content[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
```

I tried it in Chrome, and it works like a charm. I then tested it in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer, and they both don't recognize the element I'm trying to change.
They give the following error:

> Unable to get property 'removeChild' of undefined or null reference

How can I fix this so that it works in all browsers?

#### codePen

```js
function veryUsefullLibrary(parentElem) {
  var outerWrapper = document.createElement('div'),
    innerWrapper = document.createElement('div'),
    content = parentElem.children;

  function changeFunction(e) {
    console.log(content);

    content[0].removeChild(content[0].firstElementChild);
    content[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }

  while (content.length)
    innerWrapper.appendChild(content[0]);

  content = innerWrapper.children;

  var radio = document.createElement('input');
  radio.type = 'radio';
  radio.name = 'simSlider';

  radio.addEventListener('change', changeFunction);
  parentElem.appendChild(radio);

  outerWrapper.appendChild(innerWrapper);
  parentElem.appendChild(outerWrapper);

}

var overall = document.getElementById('overall'),
  lib = new veryUsefullLibrary(overall);
```

```css
#first {
  width: 500px;
  height: 386px;
}
```

```html
<div id="overall">
  <div class="content" id="first">
    <img src="https://verkoren.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/junk-dump-22918.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Id assume jQuery is not an option?

Comment: @staypuftman If that's the only way, I'd use JQuery, but I highly doubt it's not possible with pure JavaScript

Comment: Yeah I'm sure there is a way. It's just been my experience that if you rely on straight JS you often run into problems like this.

Comment: @staypuftman I understand. I'll keep that in mind! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to make it work.

```
function changeFunction(e) {
    content = innerWrapper.children;
    console.log(content);

    content[0].removeChild(content[0].firstElementChild);
    content[0].style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  }
```

Comment: Do the Microsoft browsers ignore that I already did content = innerWrapper.children?